# Transfer repository data to MVC Model

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I am getting an error

Error   826 Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable' to 'OVR.Models.ChildInfoModel'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?) C:\dev.....\Controllers\NewRecordController.cs 129 34  OVR

```
    public ActionResult ChildInfo(ChildInfoModel childInfoModel)
    {
        //INewRecord newRecord = (INewRecord)TempData["newRecord"];

        if (TempData["CertNum"].ToString() == "")
        {
            return View();
        }
        else
        {
            string certNum = (string)TempData["CertNum"];

            //call up Child Info Screen
            var repo = new Get_Home_Repository();
            childInfoModel = repo.Get_Screen_DataDS(certNum, "ChildInfo");
            //childInfoModel = cModel;

            return View(childInfoModel);
        }

    }
```

1. TempData["CertNum"] contains the value I need
2. The View is strongly typed to the model with @model OVR.Models.ChildInfoModel
3. I added in the parameter (ChildInfoModel childInfoModel) but if a link is not clicked a blank page is to be pulled up and allowed to be filled out, otherwise I pass in the parameters needed to pull data from a repository which it then populates the interface IChildInfo of which contains the data from a list as IEnumerable.  I figured I could somehow explicitly convert .. or that the Interface IChildInfo needs to get updated in order to pass back the model to the view.  How do I get the model populated from the repository data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is Get_Screen_DataDS returning?  Whats the method signature return? It seems you are returning IEnumerable from Get_Screen_DS - what is this an IEnumerable of?
You are assigning to an instance of childInfoModel which I'm assuming is not an IEnumerable but I can't really tell from what you have posted.

Should you be returning an IEnumerable? If ChildInfoModel implements IEnumerable then just simply cast it

childInfoModel = (ChildInfoModel) repo.Get_Screen_DataDS(certNum, "ChildInfo");
However in this case you should probably just hat Get_Screen_DataDS return type ChildInfoModel.

Also, it will help you much in the long haul to stick to consistent and standard .net naming conventions.

var repo would be var repository.
GetScreenDataDS would be.... GetScreenData() or GetScreenDataByCert()
FxCop rules can help you with this : ) Just my extra .00000002

Comment: The naming was in part done by another developer.... At any rate the signature is:  public IEnumerable<IChildInfo> Get_Screen_DataDS(string pCert, string pScreen)  and then the Model signature is:  public class ChildInfoModel : IChildInfo    This Oracle 9 with not being allowed to use Entity Framework is killing me.  Doing MVC without EF is driving me crazy.  I will try your solution above. Hopefully these signatures will give you a better picture of what is going on.  Yes, you now have me thinking about returning ChildInfoModel, let me know your thought on this again.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: InvalidCastException ...   Unable to cast object of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[OVR.DAL.IChildInfo]' to type 'OVR.Models.ChildInfoModel'.   When this line is hit childInfoModel = (ChildInfoModel)repo.Get_Screen_DataDS(certNum, "ChildInfo");

Comment: You can't do this. You are trying to assign a list of items from the GetScreenDataDS to a single item (your model). You need to either change the model to be a list type or change what GetScreenDataDS is returning. If you page is a strongly typed via for ChildInfoModel and not IEnumerable<ChildInfoModel> then you especially can't send a list to your view, only a single object.

Comment: I'm trying to pass out the dataset with a lambda expression into my ChildInfo properties class, 1. Is this ok to do?  2. My question I ended up posting here for the dataset/lambda expression  any help is greatly appreciated.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7134624/needing-a-dataset-to-be-captured-into-a-linq-lambda-expression

Comment: Nope you cannot automatically convert your dataset to your model. You will need to assign your columns from the first dataset row to your model.

Comment: Oh, so I did a page refresh and my data disappears.  Obviously with MVC things are a lot different, anything come to mind for retaining the data?

Comment: Your options are MVCContrib projects Html.Serialize , putting it into the cache or session, etc. And retrieving it each call. But yea viewstate is gone.

Comment: it takes some getting used to but once you have a pattern you use its not 'too' bad : )